# Version prefixes with maven release-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Can anyone tell me, if it's possible to add prefixes to the version number when using the `maven release-plugin` for version-management and releasing? Unfortunately I have no easy way to test it and since I couldn't find anything useful about this topic, I thought why not just ask the SO-community :)

(With prefixes I mean naming something `my-service-V10.7.3` instead of `my-service-10.7.3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can name the released version anything you want (using the interactive mode or the `releaseVersion` property).

So your build job or whoever calls the release plugin can determine the release version number by itself and hand it to the maven job.

Automatically adding a prefix is not possible

I would, however, advise against using version prefixes. The violate conventions.

Try to go for established version schemes, if you really need to add anything, use `10.7.3.GA` or something like that. This will also play nice with plugins and tools that determine which version is newer.

Comment: Yes, it's not my own idea to add a prefix to the version-number. I'll take the info and see what comes out of it :) Thanks!